# Match >>number and replace it

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that contains some words in the `>>number` format.

For example:

```
this is a sentence >>82384324
```

I need a way to match those `>>numbers` and replace it with another string that contains the number.

For example: `>>342` becomes

```
this is a string that contains the number 342
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this basic pattern should work:

```
>>(\d+)
```

code:

```
import re

str = "this is a sentence >>82384324"
rep = "which contains the number \\1"
pat = ">>(\\d+)"
res = re.sub(pat, rep, str)

print(res)
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/kK3tL8

Answer (score 2):

```
s= "this is a sentence >>82384324"
print re.sub("(.*\>\>)","This is a string containing " ,s)
This is a string containing 82384324
```

Comment: Just a notice with this, anything that continues after the number will also be printed. Such as `s = "This >>3959 Random"` would yield you `This is a string containing 3959 Random` which might not be the intended outcome.

Comment: @Bob The OP's examples end  with  >>82384324 so unless you know something that has not been provided my answer works for the question that was asked.

Comment: It does, however I was simply stating that IF a situation arises where there is extra characters at the end or perhaps even more than one occurrence of numbers per string that this would not work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are going to run into multiple number occurrences in a string I would suggest something a little more robust such as:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('>>(\d+)')
str = "sadsaasdsa >>353325233253 Frank >>352523523"

search = re.findall(pattern, str)
for each in search:
    print "The string contained the number %s" % each
```

Which yields:

```
>>The string contained the number 353325233253
>>The string contained the number 352523523
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using :

```
sentence = 'Stringwith>>1221'

print 'This is a string that contains
the number %s' % (re.search('>>(\d+)',sentence).group(1))
```

Result :

```
This is a string that contains the number 1221
```

You can look to the findall option to get all numbers that match the pattern [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way, assuming the only place you find ">>" is before a number, is to replace just those:

```
>>> mystr = "this is a sentence >>82384324"
>>> mystr.replace(">>","this is a string that contains the number ")
'this is a sentence this is a string that contains the number 82384324'
```

If there are other examples of >> in the text that you don't want to replace, you will need to catch the number as well, and it'll be best to use a regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('>>(\d+)','this is a string that contains the number \g<1>',mystr)
'this is a sentence this is a string that contains the number 82384324'
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html and https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html can provide more information about regular expressions.